# Which desired accuracy for CLLocationManager should I choose?

Tags: iphone, ios, gps, core-location, cllocationmanager

Does anyone know which locating-mechanisms are related to the desired accuracy of a `CLLocationManager` (e.g. `kCLLocationAccuracyBest` means GPS will be used if available) or is there any documentation?

I need good accuracy for a short period of time, but GPS might be to slow to determine the location fast enough, so I would rather use a less accurate mechanism producing the best possible data quickly.

Which `desiredAccuracy` should I use?

Comment: How short of a period are we talking? Because kCLLocationAccuracyBest will give you all the information you need in a matter of a few seconds at most.

Comment: It's exactly this amount of seconds we're talking about :) I thought methods like cell tower triangulation might be even faster...

Comment: Cell Triangulation would be a bit faster and it would use less power too, just as an added bonus. But I dont think you get as accurate of a pinpoint as you do with GPS

Comment: which accuracy you need? 30m or 1000m?

Comment: I don't think 1000m could be considered "good", but 30m and less should be okay

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just because you set kCLLocationAccuracyBest(GPS) that does not mean that you only get GPS locations:

Just configure kCLLocationAccuracyBest, then you get in the first seconds probably an 1000m inacurate fix (with attribute horiconatlAcuracy set to estimated accuracy in meters, eg. 1000), received by cell tower triangulation.

If this is sufficient then just take this.
Or wait longer until GPS delivers a location with accuracy < 30m.

Only if you want to avoid high battery usage, then avoid GPS by setting kCLLocationAccuracyKilometer.

However there is no garuantee that GPS is avoided, and Apple does not document when which mode is used by which sensor.